# Why is sql script not valid when referenced by post deploy

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have a Script.PostDeployment.sql which references DataFactoryRights.sql

ScriptPostDeployment.sql, build action PostDeploy:

```
:r .\DataFactoryRights.sql
```

DataFactoryRights.sql, build action None:

```
CREATE USER [dataFactory] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

When I try to build, I get the error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       SQL72007: The syntax check failed 'Incorrect syntax near FROM.' in the batch near:
    'CREATE USER [dataFactory] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;'

If I comment out like --:r .\DataFactoryRights.sql, it builds ok

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the T-SQL action:

```
CREATE USER [dataFactory] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

Data Factory is service principals.

Microsoft MSFT confirmed that:

"We currently don't allow service principals to create users in SQL DB. We will update the documentation when this feature is available. Thanks!"

That's why you comment out like --:r .\DataFactoryRights.sql, it builds ok.

Ref:https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/2323#issuecomment-595417579

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not the data factory that creates the user. I have managed to execute the command successfully in sql management studio